# How can I flip a modal which contains multiple divs?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, flip

How can I flip the modal below which has multiple divs?

```
<div id="modal">

 <div id="box1front" class="window">

  <div class="header">
   <div class="headerinner">
    <div class="modalclose"><a href="#" class="close">X</a></div>
    <div class="modalheading">Title</div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contents">
   <div class="other">
    <div class="otherinner">
     <button>View Back</button>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="copy">
    <div class="copyinner">
     <p>[FRONT]</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>

 <div id="box1back" class="window">

  <div class="header">
   <div class="headerinner">
    <div class="modalclose"><a href="#" class="close">X</a></div>
    <div class="modalheading">Title</div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contents">
   <div class="other">
    <div class="otherinner">
     <button>View Front</button>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="copy">
    <div class="copyinner">
     <p>[BACK]</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>

</div>
```

I would want it to flip from **box1front** to **box1back** when I click on the buttons.

There will be multiple modals on this page (obviously not all open at once). They would each have their own IDs following the format above.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone would be able to help me.

Cheers,

Ash

Comment: what do you mean by flip? like a flip effect or just change content?

Comment: Flip effect so it would go from displaying **box1front** to **box1back**

Comment: so you want the content of the modal animate the flip and by the time it has flipped the content is of the box1back?

Comment: Yes please. That would be great. Basically, **box1front** is the content that is displayed first. This contains a button. When that button is clicked, **box1front** flips round to reveal **box1back**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://blog.guilhemmarty.com/flippy/

I don't know how to do the flip(probably can if I googled a little) but the link above has the flip effect, if you google jquery flip effect there are lot of results. to change the content is easy.

Update:

```
var contentVar = $('#box1back').html();

$("#flipbox").flip({
    direction:'tb',
    content: contentVar
});
```

Something like that

Update: i did some digging and here is a working sample

http://jsfiddle.net/tvdCk/19/

Comment: Thanks. This is useful but not the exact answer. I had already come across a similar link myself which the one you found is inspired by. [lab.smashup.it/flip](http://lab.smashup.it/flip). However, I just can't seem to get it to work with my HTML code.

Comment: the implementation seems easy enough, for the content, you can store the html in a variable and then provide it as the content. I updated my answer using the link you provided

Comment: I also found this which may be helpful to some people. [css3playground.com/flip-card.php](http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php).

Comment: you can use the css3 one if you don't need to support older browsers

Comment: This is where I have got to so far... [jsfiddle.net/ashleybdesign/tvdCk/17/embedded/result](http://jsfiddle.net/ashleybdesign/tvdCk/17/embedded/result) Now I just need to be able to flip it back to show the front panel.

Comment: @Ash can you post the code you used to implement it? reply to my comment so I know you made an update

Comment: You should be able to click the '+' button in the top right-hand corner, but here is the link [jsfiddle.net/ashleybdesign/tvdCk/17/light](http://jsfiddle.net/ashleybdesign/tvdCk/17/light). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @Huangism. It doesn't seem to let me reply.

Comment: @Ash to reply you just type @ then my username, anyway I updated the answer with a working sample I hope you would be able to go from this point

Comment: Thanks @Huangism. I did try to use your username at the beginning of my reply but it didn't work unless i used your name mid-way through a sentence.